# Default /etc/sysctl.conf settings for Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, postgresql, sysctl

I tried to install PostgreSQL 9.1.2 for Mac OS X 10.6 and it asked me to edit the sysctl.conf file inside the /etc/ directory, so it could use more of the shared memory PostgreSQL was asking for.

I went ahead and edited the file, saved it, rebooted and then on the login screen I was asked to login as safe boot for some reason, I logged in and internet did not seem to work and the dock menu was laggy.

So it was pretty obvious this was happening because of the sysctl.conf file that I edited before the reboot, so I went back into the /etc directory and deleted the sysctl.conf file thinking it would auto-create a new sysctl.conf file with the default settings but that wasn't the case even after a reboot.

So now I'm pretty much left without a sysctl.conf file, I read the Mac Developer documentation for this file and it didn't say much. I know I probably shouldn't be messing with files that I don't have a clue about but I really wanted to get PostgreSQL working for my local Ruby on Rails development.

Anything on this topic would be helpful.

Comment: This might help: http://benscheirman.com/2011/04/increasing-shared-memory-for-postgres-on-os-x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine contains the following:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=134217728
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=256
kern.sysv.shmseg=64
kern.sysv.shmall=32768
```

I have Lion myself but I don't think there was anything else in it when I was using Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 7):

I have no `/etc/sysctl.conf` file on OS X 10.7.2 (Lion).

---

I suggest you save yourself a lot of headaches and install Postgres using the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager.

The steps, once XCode is installed, are:

### Install Homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

### Install Postgres

```
brew update; brew install postgres
```

### Initialize Postgres

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

### Set Postgres to run automatically

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: I got my fair share of headaches before reading this. Thanks to you, I can now continue with developing.

Comment: The up-to-date Ruby command for installing Homebrew can be found at http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: I installed Postgres using homebrew, but had to create a /etc/sysctl.conf file before I could increase the max_connections parameter.